# The IWebDriver object must implement or wrap a driver that implements IHasTouchScreen. Parameter name: driver

Tags: c#, android, appium

while coding in c# for automating native android app using appium . I have the requirement to scroll till end of the listview but when using touchactions I am facing issue "The IWebDriver object must implement or wrap a driver that implements IHasTouchScreen.
Parameter name: driver"

my code for scroll is :

```
TouchActions action = new TouchActions(driver);
            action.Scroll(listoffiles[0], 0, 300)
```

and I am using appium 1.4

Answer (score 1):

The driver needs to be passed in as `IPerformsTouchActions`.

Example:

```
driver = AppiumDriver<AppiumWebElement>(server.ServerUri, capabilities);

public static void Swipe(IPerformsTouchActions driver, int startX, int startY, int endX, int endY, int duration) 
{
    ITouchAction touchAction = new TouchAction(driver) 
    .Press (startX, startY)
    .Wait (duration)
    .MoveTo (endX, endY)
    .Release ();

    touchAction.Perform();
}
```

if you pass `driver` as an `IWebDriver` or `AppiumDriver` into the method, it will not work!

Comment: ok Thanks for the solution . I will check this and let you know if this will work.

Comment: Also i noticed you were using the TouchActions class, that is not for mobile. The Mobile actions go through TouchAction.